# using Liquid how can I get the first N variants in a for loop

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to get the first 2 variants (there are 4 total) for each product.  this seems like it would be simple but I am struggling to find a way to do it.

My current code is pretty simple:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
        {% if variant.available == true %}
            <span class="index-price">
                           ${{ variant.price | money_without_currency }} 
                        <span class="hyphen">-</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for variant in product.variants limit: 2 %}
    {% if variant.available == true %}
        <span class="index-price">
                       ${{ variant.price | money_without_currency }} 
                    <span class="hyphen">-</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```